How to apply protected ranges to all users in google sheets?
I have a code that that is doing what I want but I have one problem with it.
Basically below code is creating a protected range when the cell in AC Column is not empty and removing it when empty. Code works on edit.
It is working well but the problem is that even if the row is protected everyone can still edit the row and I have no idea how to switch it off.
Does anyone have an idea what can be wrong with my code?
function CellProtection2(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var column = range.getColumn();

  // Check if the edited cell is in column AC
  if (column == 29) { // Assuming AC is the 29th column
    var cellValue = range.getValue();
    
    // Get the range from column B to W for the edited row
    var rowRange = sheet.getRange(row, 2, 1, 23); // B2:W2 for the first row
    
    if (cellValue !== "") {
      // If AC column is not empty, protect the range from B to W in the row
      var protection = rowRange.protect().setDescription('Protected because AC column has a value');
      
      // Remove all editors
      var editors = protection.getEditors();
      for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
        protection.removeEditor(editors[i]);
      }

      // Disable domain editing
      if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
        protection.setDomainEdit(false);
      }
      
    } else {
      // If AC column is empty, remove protection from the range
      var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
      for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
        var protectionRange = protections[i].getRange();
        if (protectionRange && protectionRange.getA1Notation() == rowRange.getA1Notation()) {
          protections[i].remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


About the problem is that even if the row is protected everyone can still edit the row, if your function CellProtection2 is installed as the OnEdit trigger, for example, when the cell "AC2" is edited, the cells "B2:X2" are protected. And, those cells cannot be edited by only the owner of the Spreadsheet. Any other users cannot edit the cells. Can I ask you about the relationship between this situation and your current issue?

"Code works on edit" Please be more specific: Is this funtion being called by a simple trigger or by installable trigger? Who created the installable trigger? If you are using an installable trigger,  wow do you ensure that only one user creates the installable trigger?

only when owner of the spreadsheet will input something into AC column then it cannot be edited, but if any other user will do it then it is possible to edit

@Wicket it is called by a simple trigger 'function onEdit(e)'

@Timonek When I saw your script, I thought that the function CellProtection2 was installed as the installable OnEdit trigger. But, from it is called by a simple trigger 'function onEdit(e)', if you call the function CellProtection2fromfunction onEdit(e), that is the reason for your current issue. Please rename onEdittoinstalledOnEditand install the OnEdit trigger toinstalledOnEditand test it again. I think that of course, you can directly useCellProtection2`. But, I cannot know your whole script. So, I proposed the above.

@Tanaike I have tried it and it still not working...

Thank you for replying. About @Tanaike I have tried it and it still not working..., in this case, it is required to correctly replicate your situation. Because when I tested your script, I could not replicate your issue as mentioned in my 1st comment. I apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

@Tanaike I think I got the answer for it. In the activity dashboard only people that are in the "shared with" tab  can use it and actually protect the range.  People who are in "viewers" tab even if will input something to AC column and create protected range, everyone will be able to change it

In Google Sheets, it's not possible to apply protection that blocks all users, as the spreadsheet owner will always be able to edit any protected sheet or range.
When using a script to create, update or delete protections, to block all users except the spreadsheet owner, ensure that the script is run by the spreadsheet owner or an installable trigger created by the spreadsheet owner.
If the Google Apps Script project is contained by the spreadsheet to protect, then the easier way is to create the trigger "manually" in contrast by using code by using the Google Apps Script web app. For details, please check out https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable.
Please ensure that the function to be called by the installable trigger is not called twice by the same event, i.e., this might occur when using a simple trigger an installable trigger for the same event, like on edit.
If you create the installable trigger using code, please ensure only one for each function.
